# How do I combine local login and google login in the CakePHP Authentication plugin?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I am trying to add the feature of google login in my website which uses the CakePHP framework. For authenticating the users, I am making use of the CakePHP Authentication plugin: https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html#
After a successful redirect from the google api, I want the user to be logged in with the google credentials. To accomplish this, do I need to store the credentials of the User in the database (along with local users data)? if so, then while logging in with google, how can I pass these stored credentials to authentication plugin?

Update:
I have tried using this plugin (https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-social-auth), but while trying to install the plugin in my current project and after running composer I am receiving the following error in console:

```
  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: cakephp/cakephp[4.0.7, 3.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: cakephp/cakephp[3.x-dev, 4.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: cakephp/cakephp[3.x-dev, 4.0.7].
    - admad/cakephp-social-auth 0.6.0 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.5 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.x-dev].
    - Installation request for admad/cakephp-social-auth ^0.6.0 -> satisfiable by admad/cakephp-social-auth[0.6.0].
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp (locked at 4.0.7, required as ~4.0.7) -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[4.0.7].
```

note - I am using the latest version of cakephp i.e cakephp 4

Comment: There's a plugin that supports Google authentication, maybe you want to look into that first: **https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-social-auth/tree/cake-4.x**. If you still want to implement this on your own, my first question would be whether you already have a good general OAuth and/or OpenID knowledge?

Comment: Yes, I do possess a general knowledge of OAuth, and I am able to fetch the email (username in my website) from the google api, after the callback I am confused as to how I can validate the google user with the authentication plugin, I am currently taking a look at the supporting link.

Answer (score -2):

Create two lines in your app's Config/core.php file (or elsewhere if you have another location for app settings) similar to the following:

```
Configure::write('ExtAuth.Provider.Google.key','123456789012.apps.googleusercontent.com');
Configure::write('ExtAuth.Provider.Google.secret', 'blahblahblahblahblahblah');
```

Replace the config values with the Client ID and Client secret for your project in the Google API console.

Comment: Hey that is helpful but can you please elaborate more on what these two lines are exactly accomplishing?

Comment: This configuration belongs to an old 3rd party CakePHP 2.x plugin, and is therefore not relevant to the question.